# Configure Arquillian to test Tomcat managed Datasource

Tags: jboss, junit, jboss-arquillian

Writing a JUnit test case for a `findByFK` method. This method gets database connection from  container managed datasource. I am trying to resolve it with the help of Arquillian. I am fairly new to JUnit and 2 hrs old in Arquillian.
I have just add to my class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
```

What else I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to have a look at the [guides on the Arquillian website](http://arquillian.org/guides/). They offer gentle introduction to all the mechanics you need to understand. There is also one about testing jpa-related logic.